# Attempting to arrange files based on Date Modified

Tags: powershell

I am attempted to organise a load of PST files into sub-folders based on their modified date.

For example I would like to move a PST file with the date modified "24/09/2019" into a newly created folder called "24/09/2019" - the name of the folder being based on the date modified.

I have managed to create a dated folder based on ONE file but moving the file into the folder and completing this process on multiple files is not working.

```
$LastModifiedDate = Get-ChildItem "C:\users\user\Desktop\Test\"
$LastModified = $LastModifiedDate.LastWriteTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")

$LastModifiedDate | ForEach-Object  {
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path "C:\users\user\desktop\Test\" -Name $LastModified
    Move-Item $LastModifiedDate -Path "C:\users\user\desktop\test\$LastModified"
}

echo $LastModifiedDate
echo $LastModified
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumed your PST-Files are all located in path you specified you could use something like this:

```
$BasePath = 'C:\users\user\Desktop\Test'
Get-ChildItem -Path $BasePath -Filter *.pst |
    ForEach-Object {
        $Date = Get-Date $_.LastWriteTime -Format 'yyyyMMdd'
        $TargetPath = Join-Path -Path $BasePath -ChildPath $Date
        If (-not (Test-Path -Path $TargetPath)) {
            New-Item -Path $TargetPath -ItemType Directory -Force
        }
        Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $TargetPath
    }
```

Comment: You my friend are a hero, this has worked a treat! Thank you so much